# Can you ignore columns when doing a SSDT data compare?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, data-comparison

I frequently use the SSDT data comparison tool to sync up database data from our integration environment to our production environment.  However, I typically run into scenarios where columns should be ignored and never synced up.  Even if I review the data differences that SSDT finds, the sync operation happens on the row level and unfortunately I need to control syncing on the cell level.

Anyone have any good solutions?

Comment: I don't think SSDT offers column-level functionality. You may want to look into Red-Gate's SQL Data Compare (Pro if you need to automate). It can handle column-level comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

I just have came across this requirement in my project and in VS 2019 I have found the solution.

1. Create a new data comparison (*Tools/SQL Server/New Data Comparison...*) and
2. in the wizard after selecting the data sources click Next to have the wizard to enumerate the tables.
3. Select the desired table, expand it and unselect the fields you do not want to include in the comparison.

That's it. It was easy to overlook the little expand arrow in front of the table name...

Comment: Yes, the only exception is that you cannot ignore comparison key column.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to user an alternative tool, SSDT doesn't support this at the moment. It would certainly be nice to have.